# How to transcode or convert a live rtmp stream into hls or something a roku can recognize?

Tags: live, rtmp, roku

Looking for something I know exists but I have not found it yet. I am able to download the rtmp stream and save it to a file, but my goal is to download the steam and play it without saving it. I have learned that an mp4 will not play until a download is complete so this does me no good. Any help on sending the rtmp stream to an hls or something a roku player would recognize is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

-UPDATE-
It is possible. I have used a bat file to run rtmpdump and ffmpeg to pull a live stream to a private channel. Don't have all the bugs out yet but working on it. The bat is called from cgi script on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way. i tried alot but i didn't find a way. There is a program called wowza.You can try that.But you cannot turn your computer off,or you can upload to amazon cloudfront.It will cost you some money.

Comment: I have come across a server call Vodserver-1.3. It's suppose to grab a live stream, convert it and serve it up. Everything is written in java and utilizes xml files. Have been messing with it for several hours but for some reason can't get anything to work.